# Send many requests to a server

Tags: html, firefox, web-applications, browser

I want to send many requests (around 1000) to a server (localhost) when one of my form submitted for a test scenario. That means, the same form's GET or POST request should be sent at once. I have Firefox, Chrome, IE. Is there any tool, IDE or any other way to get this done ? Application is a Java EE app.

Comment: Have you tried googling "j2ee web load testing tools"?

Comment: If some one suppose this should be closed: then mention "why". This question is some thing like load testing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like [Apache Benchmark (ab)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)  because it's simplicity in usage, relevant result reports and easiness of install.

Comment: +1 @tudorconstantin I think your answer deserve to be marked as good.